# how to add values to the list in this format

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

how to input values in this following format because based on that, i need to perform more operations

```
for i in range(4):
   for j in range(10):
       if count < tickets:
          list[i][j] = loginId 
          #what to do instead of this statement#what is expect is, values should be assigned to each element in the list in this way how to achieve this
       else:
           break
```

what should i use instead of `list[i][j]` to assign all the values to the list.

Comment: please provide the entire code. and what do you mean by `assign all the values`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the output you requested, i modified the code

```
def fun():
    check=6
    loginID=1234
    count=0
    a=[]
    for i in range(2):
        a.append([])
        for j in range(2):
            if count<check:
                a[i].insert(j, loginID)
                count+=1
            else:
                print(a)
                break
fun()
```

You can modify the values in the ranges of for loops for more customization.

Edit : To print the above list `a` in a matrix form

```
for p in a:
    for q in p:
        print(q, end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks ..You helped me to bring up with the solution

Comment: but instead of "print (a)", if i want to access the individual element in the two dimensional list how should i do it... for eg print(a[1,1])...

Comment: You are creating a multi dimensional list (2x2) in the above code. You can access each element in the list as `a[i][j]`. For example `a[0][0]` gives you the first element in the first inner list of `a`. Likewise, you can access other elements

Comment: I wanna to gain more knowledge about multidimensional list where i can refer or gain knowledge..

Comment: @KasirajanM added code for printing it in a matrix form. This might be a good resource https://snakify.org/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/

Answer (score 0):

Full program question

```
def fun():

    check=6
    loginID=1234
    count=0
    a=[[None]*5]*4
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            if count<check:
                a[i][j]=loginID
                count+=1
            else:
                break
                print(a)

fun()
```

## output

> [[1234,1234],[1234,1234]]

I find difficult in assigning values to the matrix. please provide me a solution in this format

Comment: Please edit the original question. Unless you have the solution, there's no need to add an answer